# AFS ads on react native through bridge

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'm currently trying to implement googles search ads using a native bridge and I'm able to see the ads on native (android) and I know the bridge is working because I tested with a simple native button but I can't get these ads to show up through the bridge.

From checking the layout inspector, I can see that the SearchAdView is added to layout with the webview child but the webview's height is 0.

Anyone have any experience with this or know what might be wrong?

This is the SDK https://developers.google.com/custom-search-ads/android/

And my implementation (ids are hidden)

**React side**

```
import { requireNativeComponent } from 'react-native'

const GoogleAdView = requireNativeComponent('GoogleAdView')

export const GoogleAd = () => {
  const adRequest = {
    query: 'iphone',
    clientId: 'MY_VALID_CLIENT_ID',
    templateId: 'MY_TEMPLATE_ID',
    adTest: true
  }

  return (
    <GoogleAdView
      request={adRequest}
      style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}
    />
  )
})
```

**Android code**

```
import android.content.res.Resources
import android.util.Log
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableMap
import com.facebook.react.common.MapBuilder
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.SimpleViewManager
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ThemedReactContext
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.annotations.ReactProp
import com.google.android.gms.ads.search.DynamicHeightSearchAdRequest


class ReactGoogleAdManager : SimpleViewManager<RctGoogleAd>() {
    private companion object {
        const val REACT_CLASS = "GoogleAdView"
        const val QUERY = "query"
        const val CLIENT_ID = "clientId"
        const val TEMPLATE_ID = "templateId"
        const val AD_TEST = "adTest"
    }

    override fun getName(): String {
        return REACT_CLASS
    }

    override fun createViewInstance(reactContext: ThemedReactContext): RctGoogleAd {
        return RctGoogleAd(reactContext)
    }

    @ReactProp(name = "request")
    fun loadAds(view: RctGoogleAd, requestMap: ReadableMap) {

        val (query, clientId, templateId, adTest) = parseRequestMap(requestMap)

        val displayMetrics = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics
        val width = (view.width/displayMetrics.density).toInt()
        val height = (view.height/displayMetrics.density).toInt()
        Log.d("testlog", "container width: ${width}")
        Log.d("testlog", "container height: ${height}")

        val request = DynamicHeightSearchAdRequest.Builder()
                .setAdTest(adTest)
                .setQuery(query)
                .setNumber(1)
                .setAdvancedOptionValue("csa_adType", "plas")
                .setAdvancedOptionValue("csa_width", "128")
                .setAdvancedOptionValue("csa_height", "260")
                .setAdvancedOptionValue("csa_styleId", templateId)
                .build()

        view.searchAdView.loadAd(request)
    }

    private fun parseRequestMap(request: ReadableMap): Request {
        if (!request.hasKey(QUERY) ||
                !request.hasKey(CLIENT_ID) ||
                !request.hasKey(TEMPLATE_ID)) {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Missing required arguments! request: $request")
        }

        val query = request.getString(QUERY)
        val clientId = request.getString(CLIENT_ID)
        val templateId = request.getString(TEMPLATE_ID)
        val adTest = if (request.hasKey(AD_TEST)) {
            request.getBoolean(AD_TEST)
        } else {
            false
        }

        return Request(query, clientId, templateId, adTest)
    }

    data class Request(val query: String?,
                       val clientId: String?,
                       val templateId: String?,
                       val adTest: Boolean)
}
```

```
import android.graphics.Color
import android.util.Log
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.events.RCTEventEmitter
import com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewGroup
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize
import com.google.android.gms.ads.LoadAdError
import com.google.android.gms.ads.search.SearchAdView

class RctGoogleAd(val reactContext: ReactContext) : ReactViewGroup(reactContext) {
    val searchAdView: SearchAdView

    init {
        searchAdView = SearchAdView(reactContext).apply {
            adUnitId = "MY_ADUNIT_ID"
            adSize = AdSize.SEARCH
            adListener = object : AdListener() {
                override fun onAdLoaded() {
                    super.onAdLoaded()

                    Log.d("testlog", "loaded")

                    val parent = this@RctGoogleAd

                    measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(parent.width, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(parent.height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY))
                    layout(parent.left, parent.top, parent.left + parent.width, parent.top + parent.height)
                }

                override fun onAdFailedToLoad(error: LoadAdError) {
                    super.onAdFailedToLoad(error)
                    Log.d("testlog", error.message)

                }
            }
        }
        addView(searchAdView)
    }
}
```